# Where is the license file location for Komodo IDE 7 on Mac OS X?

Tags: komodo-ide

Where is the license file location for Komodo IDE 7.1.3 on OS X Mountain Lion?

[This information was not correct.](http://community.activestate.com/faq/where-my-activestate-lice)